# How much oxygen is needed in my atmosphere to oxidise copper 38 times faster than normal?

Tags: hard-science, earth-like, atmosphere

I would like for copper in my Earth-like world to oxidise roughly 38 times faster than copper normally does on Earth. This means that copper will turn green within around 195 days as opposed to the 20 - 25 year mark normally. I would also like for copper to somehow skip the browning phase and go straight to forming the copper carbonate (copper III, copper hydroxide, whatever you wish to call it) that gives weathered copper its signature green colour. How much oxygen is needed in the atmosphere to achieve this, and will the amount be toxic? Is this enough oxygen to skip the browning phase directly?

Comment: I would suggest a microorganism in the environment that somehow oxidizes copper very rapidly. It's possible with the right organism and chemistry. Are we talking terrestrial or alien organisms, or is it dead (unlikely with oxygen)?

Comment: Suggestion: Look into the [Deal–Grove model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deal%E2%80%93Grove_model) model, which describes how oxygen quickly rusts the surface of a metal, forming forming a [passivation layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passivation_(chemistry)) that grows.  Typically it won't be immediately visible until it's thick enough, and its growth rate slows over time since the oxygen has to diffuse through the ever-growing passivation layer to reach the not-yet-rusted metal.  This process might be sped by adding impurities and increasing surface area (e.g., rough finish).

Comment: Point being that while increasing oxygen concentration would speed up the oxidation-rate, you'd have to increase the oxygen concentration that's in contact with the metal -- not the oxygen concentration that's in the atmosphere.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### You won't get it oxidising that fast even in 100% oxygen.

[I found a source](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/isijinternational/49/12/49_12_1926/_pdf) which compares the oxidisation rate of copper at varying temperatures, humidities, and oxygen concentrations.

From conclusion section:

> While oxygen pressure did not affect the oxidation
> rate of copper, the rate was increased with increasing water
> vapor pressure due to the increased copper vacancy.

Varying oxygen levels from 20% (Earth) down to 10% or up to 100% made no notable difference on the corrosion rate of copper on its own in temperatures below 700 degrees C. And even at 700 C - the increase by switching to pure oxygen was only a tiny percentage.

To speed up your copper oxidisation you'll need also water vapor, high temperatures, and perhaps some salt or sulfur in the air. Oxygen alone just won't do it.

Comment: How can one skip the browning phase of oxidisation?

Comment: @JeffereyDawson As it happens, that browning phase is the formation of copper oxides from copper and oxygen — exactly the reaction mentioned in this answer. So, using the cited source, it would appear that your best bet for reducing the oxidation of copper would be to do exactly the opposite of what this answer recommends: …

Comment: @JefferyDawson … lower the temperature, lower the humidity, and avoid salt and sulfur. (Lowering the oxygen concentration could help as well, though per the cited source it doesn’t seem to do much.) Unfortunately, the brown state is a necessary precursor to the formation of green patina, so it seems impossible to get patina formation without going through that phase as an intermediate.

Answer (score 13):

I assume you are out in the air, and we are talking about copper clad roofs as below.

[image: green roof]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_copper_carbonate

I was interested to read that verdegris (as I would call this roof) can be various insoluble copper salts - basic copper carbonate, copper acetate and copper chloride.  So the Statue of Liberty probably has a lot of copper chloride because of the salty seawater.

But you specifically want copper carbonate.  The limiting factor is the reaction between carbonate and copper.  Preparing copper carbonate requires a basic solution with available carbonate ions.

> Basic copper carbonate is prepared by combining aqueous solutions of
> copper(II) sulfate and sodium carbonate at ambient temperature and
> pressure. Basic copper carbonate precipitates from the solution, with
> release of carbon dioxide CO 2:[6]
>
> 2 CuSO4 + 2 Na2CO3 + H2O → Cu2(OH)2CO3 + 2 Na2SO4 + CO2 Basic copper
> carbonate can also be prepared by reacting aqueous solutions of
> copper(II) sulfate and sodium bicarbonate at ambient conditions. Basic
> copper carbonate precipitates from the solution, again with release of
> carbon dioxide:
>
> 2 CuSO4 + 4 NaHCO3 → Cu2(OH)2CO3 + 2 Na2SO4 + 3 CO2 + H2O

CO2 dissolved in a basic solution will provide carbonate ions for your reaction.  If this is a roof the only realistic way to keep available water alkaline is to make the rain alkaline (or have alkaline windborne dust, which at large enough scale will also make the rain alkaline).  Is there alkaline rain?  Yes -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_precipitation

> Basic precipitation occurs when either calcium oxide or sodium
> hydroxide is emitted into the atmosphere, absorbed by water droplets
> in clouds, and then falls as rain, snow, or sleet. Precipitation
> containing these compounds can increase the pH of soil or bodies of
> water and lead to increased fungal growth.
>
> The principal cause of basic rain is emissions from factories and
> waste deposits. Mineral dust containing large amounts of alkaline
> compounds such as calcium carbonate can also increase the pH of
> precipitation and contribute to basic rain...

You could have large dry lakes in your world that are sources of carbonate salt dust storms, like Owens lake here.

[image: owens lake dust storm]

https://www.plantsciences.ucdavis.edu/news/effectiveness-and-impacts-dust-control-measures-owens-lake

The dust storm makes the rain alkaline and the basic rain catalyzes your carbonate formation.  As regards "roughly 38 times faster" this proposition is a little rougher than that.

---

My future-seeing crystal ball spotted RonJohn showing up to point out I did not answer the question!  And that question was "how much oxygen".  This process does not need molecular oxygen at all so the answer is "any amount or none".  Oxygen atoms are provided by dissolution of water in the alkaline environment to provide -OH ions.

Comment: Why are you assuming roofs?

Comment: @NomadMaker - because the OP mentions "weathered copper" and roofs are the place where copper is most weathered.  I suppose civic sculpture would be second place.  Weathering is less of an issue for copper things like coinage or IUDs.

Comment: Bracelets and other jewelry.

Answer (score 2):

## Add Humidity, Salt Water and a little Acid Rain

What we're talking about here isn't really oxygen dependent, we can speed the process up by other means. Salts and humidity will speed up the reaction rate, and the acid will help by deteriorating any protective oxide layers. This should have the desired effect without changing your oxygen concentration, which wouldn't let you reach your desired oxidation rate anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on surface area exposed (think fine granules), if you oxidize it that fast, it may not just burn — it may explode.

My “hazardous materials“ warning source:

https://nj.gov/health/eoh/rtkweb/documents/fs/0528.pdf